# how can I add some data into a CSV row which already exists in ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

For example my CSV file has first row like this
A,B,C

next I got "D" to add, but I want it in the same row like follows
A,B,C,D

not like this

A,B,C
D

is there any way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to rewrite the lines of the file, which is no big deal.  The trick is that the line has a newline on the end -- get rid of it before rewriting with `chomp`.

```
file_in = File.new("test.csv", "r")
file_out = File.new("test_out.csv", "w")
while (line = file_in.gets)
    file_out.puts "#{line.chomp},D"
end
file_in.close
file_out.close
```